# ServiceNow REST API with Table name for Alert

Tags: rest, servicenow

I have gone through the below link to know about Table REST API of ServiceNow:

https://express.servicenow.com/support/documentation/r_TableAPIGETRecordMethod/

My requirement is to obtain all the record from Alert table
using Table REST API i.e. 'GET /api/nowv1/table/(**tableName**)'.

Now my question is , what will be the name of the (**tablename**) for Alert in the API itself to get the alerts which are already created in the table and can be seen using via "manage the alert life cycle feature" by navigating "Event Management > Active Alerts"  (See : http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Managing_Alerts#Managing_the_Alert_Life_Cycle) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're an administrator, you can get the table name from the table label (e.g. "Alert") by going to the `sys_db_object` table (via "Tables" entry in the left nav).
Just search for the row with the label you want, and the table name will be the `name` of that row.

As any other user, you can just open any record in the table in a new tab/window (i.e. outside of the usual frameset) and look at the URL.

For your case, I opened "All Alerts", then opened an arbitrary record, which took me to this url suffix:

`/em_alert.do?sys_id=df7a6f00d72321008de76ccf6e610322`

This tells us that the table name for "All Alerts" is `em_alert`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

In order to work with servicenow event/alert, you need to plugin the Event Management module in your PaaS developer instance, if you are new in ServiceNow.

This link (https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/home ) is for applying for new developer instance. First you need to register and then you will be getting the instance. Once you have the instance allocated, you are provissioned to add "Event Management" plugin and then your developer instance (so far free)  is a place for you to learn about ServiceNow Event Management system for doing research & development on event/alert  table API etc. **Note** : The developer instance may not support real monitoring features e.g. : (1) detect an event; (2) send an alert of an event;

The API for getting alert info will be :
GET https://.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/em_alert with basicauth credential

regards
SK